# change button hover state via JS when the hover state was touch event triggered

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-chrome-devtools

A strange situation when a number of **mobile users** experience weird behavior on `iPhone 11`:

**HTML button element does not change state - it keeps its `:hover` state after click/tap event**

How to best force/change the DOM state of the `button element` by using JavaScript?

```
<button id="whateverID">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="check" data-prefix="far" id="ember1228" class="svg-inline--fa fa-check fa-w-16 ember-view">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M435.848 83.466L172.804 346.51l-96.652-96.652c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.971 0l-28.284 28.284c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971l133.421 133.421c4.686 4.686 12.284 4.686 16.971 0l299.813-299.813c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971l-28.284-28.284c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.97 0z"></path>
  </svg> in basket
</button>
```

The below jQuery request returns `true`:

```
$('#whateverID').is(":hover")
```

*We would like to execute some JavaScript so that the command above returns `false`

Perhaps the fixing code would be attached to the `tap event` or `click event`.*

**IMPORTANT** please replicate the issue first, before posting any solutions.
To replicate open Chrome DevTools and simulate a mobile device, then touch the button.

For example, a click away from the button solves the issue, but we would like not to have to click away, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In anticipation of improved browser support for `:hover` state on touch devices and accepted best approach to solve the issue: [this Mozilla developer article](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) has the following disclaimers:

> **Note:** The `:hover` pseudo-class is problematic on touchscreens.
> Depending on the browser, the `:hover` pseudo-class might never match,
> match only for a moment after touching an element, or continue to
> match even after the user has stopped touching and until the user
> touches another element. Web developers should make sure that content
> is accessible on devices with limited or non-existent hovering
> capabilities.

For Safari browser we have:

> As of Safari for iOS 7.1.2, tapping a [clickable element](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile) causes the
> element to enter the :hover state. The element will remain in the
> :hover state until a different element has entered the :hover state.

For Edge browser we have:

> In Edge, hovering over an element and then scrolling up or down
> without moving the pointer will leave the element in the :hover state
> until the pointer is moved. See [bug 5381673](https://developer.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5381673/).

For Internet Explorer we have:

> In Internet Explorer 8 to Internet Explorer 11, hovering over an
> element and then scrolling up or down without moving the pointer will
> leave the element in the :hover state until the pointer is moved. See
> [bug 926665](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/926665).

> In Internet Explorer 9 (and possibly earlier), if a 
> has a parent with a non-auto width, [overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/width): auto;, the  has
> enough content to horizontally overflow its parent, and there are
> [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) styles set on elements within the table, then hovering over
> said elements will cause the 's height to increase. [See a live
> demo that triggers the bug](http://jsbin.com/diwiqe). One workaround for the bug is to set
> min-height: 0%; (the % unit must be specified, since unitless and px
> don't work) on the 's parent element.

**See also**

- [Chromium bug #370155: Don't make `:hover` sticky on tap on sites that
  set a mobile viewport](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370155)
- [Chromium bug #306581: Immediately show hover
  and active states on touch when page isn't scrollable.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306581)